# raspberry pi led does not blink

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a led blink every second. This is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
try:
    while True:
        gpio.output(20, 1)
        time.sleep(1)
        gpio.output(20, 0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        gpio.cleanup()
```

The problem is that my LED just turns on and it does not blink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't sleep after you do `gpio.output(20, 0)`. Thus, it instantly turns back on when it repeats the while loop. Do this:

```
while True:
    gpio.output(20, 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    gpio.output(20, 0)
    time.sleep(1)
```